# Cannot able to import FieldInputProps react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes, react-final-form, final-form

Trying to set actual propTypes. But show error like this

> Attempted import error: 'FieldInputProps' is not exported from 'react-final-form'.

```
import { FieldInputProps, FieldMetaState } from 'react-final-form';

const TextInput = ({
  input: { name, onChange, value, type = 'text', placeholder, ...restInput },
  meta
}) => {
  .....Some Component Functionality.....
};

TextInput.propTypes = {
  input: FieldInputProps,
  meta: FieldMetaState
}
```

Am not sure why this happens, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of react-final-form in package.json. I have no errors in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-jennings-i32w6?file=/src/App.js, was using 6.5.2

Comment: I'm also using the same version.Please check console